# The philosophy of friendship

Tags: ethics, reference-request, relations, human-nature

I am new to philosophy. 
Are there any good writings on what friendship means? 
I came across something on
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/friendship/. How good is this website? Is it good for beginners?

Comment: Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy is a good starting point for any topic in philosophy. You can go deeper into the subject by looking at the bibliography cited.

Comment: There are many philosophical works on friendship. It is in many ways a basis of philosophy itself, for it requires a discourse in which one can share exposure to falsification and acknowledge the truth in another. Aristotle has two books on friendship in the Nicomachean Ethics, it is addressed by Seneca, Cicero, Montaigne, and by Deleuze and Guattari in "What Is Philosophy?"  Among many others, I'm sure. One can translate "philosophy" not only as "lover of" wisdom, but as "friend of" wisdom.